# Cannot use IOptionsMonitor to detect changes in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working on Asp.Net Core app

I want to change the configuration settings after running the application

I am using IOptionsMonitor, but it is not detecting changes

In Startup.cs -> Configuration() method I have

```
services.Configure<Config>(Configuration.GetSection("someConfig"));
```

In a different class where these config settings are read, I wrote something like

```
var someConfig= serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<Config>>();
```

But when I change the configuration file (Json File), the change is not detected, and someConfig does not change.

Config POCO class:

```
public class Config
{
    public string name {get; set;}
    //More getters and setters
}
```

**Edit:**

```
services.AddSingleton<ConfigHelpers>;
```

I am using a singleton object in which I am trying to read the config. It works fine if its not a snigleton. Is there a way to change the config even in a singleton object ?

in ConfigHelpers.cs

```
var someConfig= serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<Config>();
```

since it is defined as singleton in Startup.cs, changes made to Config are not reflected.

Comment: Did you set the reloadChanges flag to "true" for your settings file?

Comment: @SimplyGed yes I did.

Comment: @PHPMODE Could you replace `IOptionsMonitor` with `IOptionsSnapshot`?

Comment: @win Tried it, its not working. I am trying to open the config JSON file and change it manually (Save -> close). Is this how it works ?

Comment: Have you tired to change **AddSingleton** to **AddScoped**?  If that helps, then I would change the way you are using ConfigHelper in your project.

Comment: @Thowk It works with Scoped and Transient, But I need to use Singleton.

Answer (score 8):

Did you create your *WebHostBuilder* like this aprox:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("config.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

var AppConfig = config.Get<AppConfig>();

var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseUrls("http://*:" + (AppConfig.Port ?? 80))
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseIISIntegration()
    // Clones your config values
    .UseConfiguration(config)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

Then it will clone your values and you'll loose the live reload ability.

You'll have to use **ConfigureAppConfiguration** and do the following:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseUrls("http://*:" + (AppConfig.Port ?? 80))
    .UseKestrel()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builder, conf) =>
    {
        conf.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("config.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .UseIISIntegration()
    //.UseConfiguration(config)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 1):

After a long day with .NET Core 3.1 reading the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1), various blog and forum posts and implementing all the suggested variations of IOptionsMonitor, IOptions, IOptionsSnapshot, IConfiguration, IServiceCollection and IServiceProvider, the only way I could get a dynamic update to work with the JsonConfigurationProvider (appsettings.json) and ConfigureWebHostDefaults() was this rather ugly workaround that could be implemented in a singleton as per the question:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Reference to the application IConfiguration implementation
    /// </summary>
    static IConfiguration configuration;

    /// <summary>
    /// Reference buffer for Configuration property
    /// </summary>
    static AppConfiguration appConfiguration = new AppConfiguration();

    /// <summary>
    /// Access to the current configuration
    /// </summary>
    public static AppConfiguration Configuration
    {
        get
        {
                configuration.Bind("AppConfiguration", appConfiguration);
                return appConfiguration;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To detect configuration changes, a listener must be registered to the `IOptionsMonitor` by using its [`OnChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptionsmonitor-1#methods) method.

Example on a `BackgroundService`:

```cs
// ...
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Threading;

public class MySingletonService : BackgroundService
{
    private IDisposable _optionsChangedListener;
    private MyOptions _myCurrentOptions;

    public MySingletonService(IOptionsMonitor<MyOptions> optionsMonitor)
    {
        _optionsChangedListener = optionsMonitor.OnChange(MyOptionsChanged);
        _myCurrentOptions = optionsMonitor.CurrentValue;
    }

    private void MyOptionsChanged(MyOptions newOptions, string arg2)
    {
        _myCurrentOptions = newOptions;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_myCurrentOptions.MyProperty);
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        _optionsChangedListener.Dispose();
        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

```
public class MyOptions
{
    public const string SectionKey = "MyOptions";

    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was really having a hard time troubleshooting this with a BackgroundService and the example you gave was crystal clear and I was able to resolve my issue.